# Dynamic creation of cobra commands based on directory specified by flag

Tags: go-cobra

We already add cobra commands dynamically based on the current directory context (adding them in init()). If certain things are available in the directory, commands get added.

Now there's a requirement to use a flag to decide what directory to operate in. But we've always added flags and commands in init(), and flags don't get processed in time to use them for command creation.

So the idea is that `ddev -r /Users/rfay/workspace/one` might display a different set of commands than `ddev -r /Users/rfay/workspace/two`. How could the command generation be affected by a flag already proceessed?